# How to add numbers in column two if column one is the same in Python?

Tags: python, list

If I have sample input:

```
Apples,2
Apples,4
Apples,1
Oranges,10
Oranges,2
```

How can I get output like following:

```
Apples,7
Oranges,12
```

Thanks.

Edit:  I'm using Python 3

Comment: what is the input type? from file? strings? tuples?

Answer (score 2):

use a defaultdict.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d=defaultdict(int)
with open('inputfile') as f:
    for line in f:
        fruit,num = line.split(',')
        #could also use `fruit,num,*rest = line.split(',')` 
        #for a little more robustness at the expense of 
        #backward compatability
        d[fruit]+=int(num)
```

You could also use the `csv` module to parse the columns from the file, but that seemed overkill to me in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

[Counters](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) are designed specifically for this.

```
# I'm assuming you have a list or iterable of lines like this
file="""Apples,2
Apples,4
Apples,1
Oranges,10
Oranges,2""".split('\n')

# Here's the code under that assumtion
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce
from operator import add
tally = reduce(add, (Counter({x[0]: int(x[1])}) for x in (x.split(',') for x in file)))

# To demonstrate
for name in tallies:
print('%s,%s' % (name, tallies[name]))
```

Comment: I'm not sure that a `Counter` is the best thing here since `Counter.update` doesn't accept an iterable of `(key,value)` pairs which is what we have here.

Comment: thats pretty cool ... I havent really messed with Counters (oh maybe thats cause I havent really messed with py3)

Comment: This gives me `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @JoranBeasley -- Counters are introduced in python2.7.  This usage is basically the same as a `defaultdict` though.  Where they really shine is when you look at `update` (and the constructor) and also their additional methods like `most_common` and `elements`.  They're pretty cool.

Comment: @alan does it raise the IndexError exception during the `for` block or when other code uses the `tallies` counter? (since `Counter` is an iterable, not a `dict`, it behaves differently in certain contexts.)

Comment: @Jordan the Exception is on this line `tallies[tally[0]] += int(tally[1])` It's the only place where there is an index.

Comment: @Jordan Never mind. My bad. I made a mistake when I copy/pasted your code to try it. It works fine.

Comment: @mgilson thanks :) ... I primarily use py2.6 so that also explains why I hadnt seen it

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(int)
lines = """
Apples,2
Apples,4
Apples,1
Oranges,10
Oranges,12
"""
for k in lines.splitlines():
    result[k.split(",")[0]]+=int(k.split(",")[-1] or 0)#account for '' cases...
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stuff = """
Apples,2
Apples,4
Apples,1
Oranges,10
Oranges,2
"""

# Holds mapping from fruit->count    
total = {}

# Process input    
lines = stuff.strip().splitlines()

for x in lines:
    name, _, count = x.partition(",")
    total.setdefault(name, 0)
    total[name] += int(count)

# Output
for k, v in sorted(total.items()):
    print("{},{}".format(k, v))
```

(don't have Python 3 installed on this machine, but the above should work, possibly with minor tweaks)

Answer (score 0):

```
strs="""Apples,2
Apples,4
Apples,1
Oranges,10
Oranges,2"""

dic={}
for x in strs.split():
    key=x.split(',')[0]
    val=int(x.split(',')[1])    
    dic[key]=dic.get(key,0)+val

print(dic)  #prints {'Apples': 7, 'Oranges': 12}
```

Answer (score 0):

No love for groupby?

```
data = """\
Apples,2
Apples,4
Apples,1
Oranges,10
Oranges,2""".splitlines()

from itertools import groupby

groups = groupby((line.split(',') for line in data), key=lambda x:x[0])
table = dict((k,sum(map(int,(x[1] for x in vals)))) for k,vals in groups)
for item in table.items():
    print '%s,%d' % item
```

Prints:

```
Apples,7
Oranges,12
```